# Ноль (нуль) - числительное или существительное?

Tags: части-речи

Какой частью речи является слово "ноль" ("нуль")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, проблема в том, что словом "ноль" **сейчас** обозначают и число и цифру. Различие "ноль-нуль", упомянутое **LiveStreet**, размыто. В разговорном языке для обоих случаев используют "ноль", а в многочисленных жаргонах (кроме математического) - "нуль"...

Видимо, надо смотреть по контексту (когда "ноль" рассматривается как цифра - существительное, когда как число - числительное).

Comment: Это что-то новенькое. Понятие "цифры" грамматика не знает.

Comment: ну так, пора бы и озаботиться, чай не 16-й век. числа знает и цифр не знает, но  употребляет,  латиница и ее цифирь, это как? числительные или существительные?

Comment: @Niemand название цифры ("единица","двойка" и т.д.) - это существительное. Название числа ("один","два" и т.д.) - числительное.
Если название числа и цифры совпадает - возникает неопределённость. Которую надо решать исходя из контекста.
Со словами "тысяча", "миллион" и т.д. так-же возникает неопределённость, но по другой причине. Они используются в записи числительного как "разделители" для разрядов.

Comment: @greydog, цифры и числа тут ни при чем. Зачем фантазировать? Есть грамматические признаки существительного, а есть – числительного. Исходя из них, *сто* – числительное, а *сотня* – существительное. А *тысяча* ничем от *сотни* не отличается, поэтому она такое же существительное. За исключением случаев, когда входит в состав составного числительного.

Comment: числительные, это слова, при помощи которых осуществляется, именно словами, запись чисел, а числа состоят из цифр. Сами по себе эти слова все существительные, от них прилагательные, типа: нулевой, двойственный, глаголы, типа: удвоить и тд.
Ноль в этом качестве не участвует, кроме как в кривой записи числа 100-один два нуля.
но вот куда отнести вот такое, вам грамота.ру  боюсь не ответит.
один полста девять--не числительные? это давно не сленг. полтораста, тоже не сленг. и полтина с  полтинником -идиомами не являются.

Comment: @Niemand Я прекрасно понимаю, что "числительные" (равно как и "собственные") - не более, чем подмножество имён существительных. Но. Приведён конкретный пример. Слово, которое означает число, но ведёт себя не как числительное.

Я - человек дотошный, и пытаюсь разобраться - почему так. И, если "сто" и "сотня" - разнятся и в написании, и в значении, образуя своего рода "пару", то "ноль", "тысяча" и "миллион" - "парных числительных" не имеют. Числа - есть, а числительные - отсутствуют (или, по другой версии - числительные ведут себя как существительные). Вот это я и пытаюсь объяснить.

Comment: @petro Слово "ноль" участвует в записи числа "ноль". Если Вы этого не понимаете, то рекомендую проконсультироваться у учителя начальных классов.

Comment: не участвует, а обозначает, не число, а его отсутствие, а точнее признак,  в слове сто, если вы видите, ноля нет, от только подразумевается в количестве двух после единицы. тож самое и миллион в количестве шести штук, дак на то и приставка милли.  как раз шесть.

Comment: **Число** ноль является точно таким же числом, как и все остальные. Не верите - спросите у любого учителя математики.

Вы же упорно путаете число и цифру, служащую для его записи.

Comment: У вас тавтология, "число ноль является числом".  Слово ноль, обозначает якобы число, а точнее запись обозначения, не имеющее численного значения, счетными свойствами не обладающего, в общем это признак переноса в позиционной системе счисления из разряда в разряд. В графиках это позиция начала отсчета, просто точка, кружок без дырки... Точка не является числом. И уж к числительным его относят только не знающие принципов систем счисления, то есть математики. А если учителя у нас такие, то и грош им цена как математикам. Математика,  точная наука. Путаница в определениях делает ее фарсом.

Answer (score 2):

Нуль - числительное, а ноль - существительное. Это разные слова. Нуль - точка на числовой оси, такая же, как один, два и т. д. , а ноль - синоним слова "ничего".

Comment: *ноль* на русском
*нуль* на украинском

Answer (score 1):

Нулевой рабочий провод.

Нулевая отметка.

Нулевой километр.

Скорее нуль -- существительное и от него прилагательное - нулевой.
Ноль (число) — число, от прибавления, а также вычитания которого никакое число не меняется.
Ноль (цифра) — цифра «0» для обозначения числа ноль.
В латыни nullus - ничто. Две производные - НУЛЬ и НОЛЬ. В двух вариантах: современный украинский и русский.
Вообще - точка отсчета, так что и не числительное, понятие не является счетным. Но считается по-странному числом, хотя и не является числом, псевдо участвует в арифметических действиях, а деление на ноль вообще абракадабра.

Цифра!!!  Это обозначение ничего не значащее. Дырка от бублика. HOLE.  Аналог в русском ГОЛЬ.
В математике еще и обозначение (признак) перехода из разряда в разряд в любой позиционной системе счисления.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматика говорит, что существительное. Что? — нуль. Основные признаки существительного (которые отсутствуют у количественных числительных): род, число. Итак, мужской род, единственное число. Существительные также изменяются по числам? — пожалуйста: нуль — нули. Второй тип склонения (как, например, у существительного *конь*).

Что же заставляет сомневаться? То, что слово "нуль", как и количественные числительные, обозначает некоторое количество... Но все же грамматические признаки важнее.

Comment: некоторое, это какое? количество нулей, это да. А ноль - пустое множество, абстракция.

 И не друг, и не враг, а - так,
Если сразу не разберешь,
Плох он или хорош...

аналог черного квадрата, восхитительная живопись маслом, для тех, кто понимает.

Comment: Это Вы о чём?

Или - просто чтоб хоть что-то сказать?

Comment: Черное - не белое.  белое - не черное,  ноль  - нечто. не количество и не качество.
так по себе, ничтожество. О том и речь. Грамматически одно, а по жизни то, ноль.

Answer (score 1):

По своим грамматическим признакам слова ***тысяча, миллион, миллиард, ноль, нуль*** ближе к существительным.   Так они большинством лингвистов и характеризуются. При этом ***тысяча, миллион, миллиард*** могут быть и числительными -- в том случае, когда называют соответствующее число или обозначают соответствующее количество.

Что же касается ***нуля…*** Сошлюсь на "Грамматику-80". Она хоть и считает слова  ***нуль*** и ***ноль*** существительными,  всё же пишет, что существуют и другие точки зрения:

> **§ 1366 …**   Термин "числительное" традиционно употребляется также для
> наименования всех слов с
> количественно-числовым и
> счетно-порядковым значениями. Такие
> слова отвечают на вопросы "сколько?" и
> "который?": *два, три, пятеро, тысяча,
> миллион, **нуль** (и **ноль**)…*
>
> http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html

Comment: нуль не является счетным, ни порядковым, сколько? да ни чего сколько. который ?, да ни который.  Ноль и есть ноль, к числительным никакого отношения. Не число, - признак только призрачный.  вместо ноля можно и апостроф, а что такое апостроф?

Comment: petro, а от пяти отнять пять сколько будет? Апостроф? Или всё же ноль?

Comment: а хоть прочерк, дело привычки.